# How to open a child browser window and then execute a script on the newly loaded child browser page to click a link in it

Tags: javascript, url, popup, zoho

I have 2 web applications A and B (for those familiar with Zoho, A is Zoho Creator and B is Zoho Invoice)

From web application A, I need to open a page within Application B and get to a particular view in B which can only be obtained by clicking a link on the page in B (as that view is obtained by an AJAX load of the view).

Limitation of B is that it does not expose the particular view I want by means of a URL with paramaeters (i.e. I can't get what I want just by having a new browser window request www.appB.com/somePage?ID=1233. I can only have the new browser window request www.appB.com/somePage and then I need to manually click an AJAX link in B that opens up a view I want).

Limitation of A is that I do not have access to javascript. I have limited means (Zoho Creator's Deluge language) to open another web application in a new browser window. All I can do is give the webpage of A a URL and tell it open it in the same window or a new window. So only manipulative capability I have on webpage of A when opening a new browser window is the new webpage's URL.

What I want to accomplish is - From webpage of A just via URL open new browser window that loads the initial page of B and then my javascript executes and clicks on the link on B that loads the desired AJAX view in the B's browser window.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work? Your inputs are much appreciated and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you don't have javascript in A or in B, where is your javascript running from?   Also, are A and B in the same domain?

Comment: In A, I cannot run javascript. I would like to inject some javascript in B - possibly by means of the URL that opens B. A & B are not in the same domain.

Comment: URL parameters cannot inject javascript.  It doesn't sound like you have any ability to run javascript in A or B.  FYI, when A and B are different domains, you can't use javascript from one to act on the other either because of same-origin security restrictions in the browser.  It sounds like you need modifications to page B so that it will load a view based on a URL parameter.

Comment: Hmm... I have no control over B :( ! Else would have already implemented the URL parameter. Appreciate you looking into my problem. If you have any other thoughts do share them. Thanks.

Comment: Moiz, Can you tell me the name of the View you want to open? Maybe I'll talk with Zoho Invoice team about this.

Comment: Great! In a Zoho creator view I have list of Creator created Invoices and an action button next to each invoice called "Add Payment". When the "Add Payment" button is clicked, I need to bring the user to the "Record Payment" view that you get when the "Add Payment" link below the Zoho Invoice is clicked. The problem right now is this "Record Payment" cannot be arrived at via a URL call as it seems to be an AJAX view inside Zoho Invoice. My customer would be really delighted if the Zoho Invoice team and have it time for the upcoming release. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the conclusions in my previous comments:

1. You cannot inject javascript into a page via the page URL.  You could pass parameters in the URL, but the receiving page would need to already be coded to act on those parameters.
2. You cannot use javascript from one page to act on another page if the two pages are in different domains and not pre-designed to cooperate.  This is security restriction called same origin policy which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).
3. So, if you can't modify page B in any way and B is in a different domain than A and A and B were not predesigned to cooperate, then you can't click the link in B from A.

Comment: the only way its through making extention